# Can't install the proprietary ATI graphics driver

Tags: software-installation

When I try to install my graphics driver it shows that...

> One or more tools requied for installation cannot be found on the
>   system. install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.
>   optionaly, run the installer without --force to install the tools.
>   Forcing install will disable the AMD hardaware acceleration and may
>   make your syatem unstable. not recommended. see
>   /usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log for more details.

I installed `fglrx` and tried again, but it did not work. And a system problem was detected during installing the `fglrx`.

It's very important to install my graphics driver for my job!

The graphics driver also does not appear in the additional drivers.

What can I do?

---

`/usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log` shows

```
Check if system has the tools required for installation. 
fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers. 
/lib/modules/3.8.0-33-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system. 
One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. 
Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver. 
Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools. 
Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your system unstable. 
Not recommended.
```

Comment: How about you show us the `/usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log` log?

Comment: Edit the question... **DO NOT USE COMMENTS**

Comment: You must provide more information in order to get help. Please open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and issue these commands one by one `lsb_release -rcd;uname -rm` , `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga` , `X -version` . Then edit your question and add the additional info.

Comment: @anik [edit] your question! also, show us the content of the log file. Repeat the following command `lspci -nnk | grep -A5 VGA`.

Comment: @anik - comments SHOULD NOT be used to respond with information.  I have deleted those comments.  Please edit your question with any replies.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need your kernel headers to install fglrx. To install them is easy:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

now **reboot your system**. If you do not reboot the installation will continue failing.

---

Be aware that most of the time the **proprietary drivers are not necessary**, unless you have a very recent/new graphic card.

Comment: `linux-headers-<KERNEL-VERSION>` package should be installed by default. Actually, it is installed by default. I guess that the problem resides on Xorg version and graphics card model. But until OP gives us more information, I cannot be sure.

Comment: @NikTh I'm taking `/lib/modules/3.8.0-33-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found` message as parting point. The package that keeps the headers installed and updated is `linux-headers`. I'm guessing that somehow he managed to prevent the headers from being updated/installed. My method do both, install the latest image and headers. If you want to check do `aptitude why linux-headers-$(uname -r)` to see the real reason why the headers are installed ;).

Answer (score 0):

after installing kernel headers you should also do 
`sudo apt-get install gcc`
it worked for me well